# SQL Count() - Selecting the same row more than once

Tags: sql, count, coldfusion-10

I'm currently re-working the size filter i built earlier this year for our website. The size filter query works off the `stock_id`'s found in the `products` query. On occassions, the same product can appear many times, due to it being a single listing as well as appearing inside a mix and match listing.

Because the `stock_id` remains the same however, whenever i run a query using `stock_id In (#products.stock_id#)`, i only get the one row, when because lets say `products.stock_id` equals `1234,1234,1235`. `1234` will only be shown once rather than twice, how do i get this record to be counted twice? I know it's not the most straightforward of questions but i don't have much time to dedicate to this post unfortunately.

**EDIT 1 - Size Filter Query**

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#" name="size_filter">
    Select size_id,
        size_description,
        size_count
    From sizes

    Inner Join (
        Select stock_sizeid,
            Count(*) As size_count
        From stock
        Where stock_id In (#valueList(products.stock_id)#)
        And stock_sizeid Not In ('33','218')
        And stock_instock > 0
        Group By stock_sizeid
    ) As stock
    On size_id = stock_sizeid

    Order By size_description Asc
</cfquery>
```

Comment: post some queries, some table information, etc. How are you getting the 'size' value?

Comment: @AdrianNasui I'll do that now, i'll add it on to the end of the post. I get it from using `Inner Join` of the stock table onto the products table.

Comment: You might want to use left join and you get your desired result

Comment: @AdrianNasui No, the products query is fine. It's the following query where i run a check on the sizes table and inner join the stock, then select the stock records based on the ID's found within the original query. There can be more than one of the same stock id due to having items within outfits. The size filter needs to reflect the item being available in that specific size separately AND within the outfit too, rather than just one or the other.

Comment: post the query that you use for COUNT

Comment: @AdrianNasui Done, it's above. Hope that's a little more clear as to what i'm attempting to achieve. It's in the `products.stock_id` where the same ID could appear twice, but the record will only be accounted for once. I want the record to technically be selected for every time it is encountered in that list.

Comment: What's this got to do with ColdFusion-10 (or any version of it). It's just an SQL question, yes? But given you've tagged it as such, you should not be hard-coding dynamic values into the SQL string, you should be passing them as params.

Comment: @AdamCameron Because you never know what clever server side code people know to get round these kind of issues. If i at least show the server code i use people know what to recommend. Also, i normally use `<cfqueryparam>` tags, however 1. the length of the list can exceed the allowed limit for `<cfqueryparam>` value and 2. these values are taken from another query therefore sanitization of the input isn't necessary anyway.

Comment: Using parameters is not about "sanitising" input, it's about keeping your values separate from your statement, and about letting your queries compile. If you're breaking the limit of how many params the DB can handle in a list... you've got bigger problems than this anyhow, I guess. That and it looks like your data isn't normalised properly either :-(

Comment: @AdamCameron I appreciate your point. We perhaps don't do things to the best they could be done. I always prefer to use `<cfqueryparam>` but this is why i need to learn new things such as creating temporary tables rather than relying on the `In` statement for rather huge lists. Yes, data isn't normalised properly but that's out of my control for now unfortunately.

Comment: Hey @LeeB: it's often the way, mate. if I was indicting anything, it was the situation, not you.

Comment: Don't worry @AdamCameron, i'm still a young developer and any hints or tips along the way will only help me improve.

Comment: *the length of the list can exceed the allowed limit* I would recommend looking at either a) combining the `products` query with the above or b) temp tables. Can you post the SQL for the `products` query AND include your dbms type?

Comment: *the same ID could appear twice, but the record will only be accounted for once* Because the `count(*)` function does not know, or care, how many times that id appears in the `IN (..)` clause. It simply counts matching records in the "stock" table. Since the "stock" table only contains one record with stock_id=1234, the `count()` will always be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Cheat, and `JOIN` to your id list (instead of using an `IN` clause):

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#" name="size_filter">
    Select size_id,
           size_description,
           size_count
    From sizes

    Inner Join (Select stock_sizeid,
                       Count(*) As size_count
                From stock
                Join (Select stock_id
                      From (VALUES(#valueList(products.stock_id)#)) a(stock_id)) As ids
                  On ids.stock_id = stock.stock_id
                Where stock_sizeid Not In ('33','218')
                      And stock_instock > 0
                Group By stock_sizeid) As stock
            On size_id = stock_sizeid

    Order By size_description Asc
</cfquery>
```

To make `VALUES()` give rows instead of columns, the correct form is `VALUES(1), (2), ...(n)`.  I'm assuming `valueList(...)` is some client-side procedure that gets run when the statement gets prepared; you'll need to provide an equivalent function to produce this output.

(Note, I've never used coldfusion, so I don't know if this actually works.  This type of thing works in *most* RDBMSs, although some complain)

What this is doing is turning your list into a virtual table, which has all your entries in it, so the `JOIN` will be assessed multiple times, as normal.

Comment: I like your thinking. A vartual table might just work, and if i'm thinking right is probably a better use than using the `In` operator anyway. I'll give this a try and let you know the outcome.

Comment: @LeeB - Creating all sorts of virtual/temp tables to join to is great fun, because it puts the problem set into something the DB can (often) optimize better, and fits better in an SQL paradigm.  Grouping by month?  Create a range table.  Converting from a Boolean to a `Yes`/`No` string?  Create a conversion table.  Most RDBMSs don't let you supply arrays for `VALUES()` or `IN()`, but often allow bulk `INSERT`s to tables, even to temp tables (or you can trivially create a table-function that accepts a delimited string.  Poof, no dynamic SQL, way more difficult for SQL injection).

Comment: It's definitely something i'll practice further with going forward, definitely seems like a great way to go about things. I'm having a slight issue with the above query, whenever there is more than one value within the `Values()` parameter it throws an error saying "a has more columns than were specified in the column list".

Comment: Whups, I forgot to add an explanation about that.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, i did begin to realise that yesterday. Going to come up with some kind of function to make my queries more capable of doing these things.

Comment: Personally I would recommend using a derived table or temp table instead. I have never seen VALUES used in a SELECT. Does the example above actually work? If yes, in which dbms?

Comment: @Leigh - DB2,SQL Server, PostgreSQL.  Oracle doesn't support multi-row `VALUES()` statements, so you have to `UNION SELECT...` instead.  MySQL doesn't seem to either, probably have to pull the same trick as in Oracle.

Comment: Huh. Learn something new every day. Though as you mentioned earlier, given the number of values, temp tables (or the like) are probably a better option. They might even be able to combine the two queries as well, but it is hard to say without more details.